# Stata seems to be ignoring my starting values in maximum likelihood estimation

Tags: stata

I am trying to estimate a maximum likelihood model and it is running into convergence problems in Stata. The actual model is quite complicated, but it converges with no troubles in R when it is supplied with appropriate starting values. I however cannot seem to get Stata to accept the starting values I provide.

I have included a simple example below estimating the mean of a poisson distribution. This is not the actual model I am trying to estimate, but it demonstrates my problem. I set the trace variable, which allows you to see the parameters as Stata searches the likelihood surface.

Although I use init to set a starting value of 0.5, the first iteration still shows that Stata is trying a coefficient of 4.

Why is this? How can I force the estimation procedure to use my starting values?

Thanks!

```
generate y = rpoisson(4)

capture program drop mypoisson
program define mypoisson

args lnf mu

quietly replace `lnf' = $ML_y1*ln(`mu') - `mu' - lnfactorial($ML_y1) 
end

ml model lf mypoisson (mean:y=)
ml init 0.5, copy
ml maximize, iterations(2) trace
```

Output:

```
   Iteration 0:
   Parameter vector:
        mean:
       _cons
   r1         4
```

Comment: At a guess, your program name `poisson` may be the problem. As Stata has an inbuilt command `poisson`, that will always get executed in preference. You can test this by changing your program name to something else. `which myname` tests for a command `myname`.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion Nick. The name does not seem to be the problem. I wonder if I am looking at the wrong output when trying to see the parameter values that are being used? Or else I may be doing something wrong as I try to set the initial values?

Answer (score 1):

Added:  Stata doesn't ignore the initial value.  If you look at the output of  the `ml maximize` command, the first line in the listing will be titled

> initial:       log likelihood =

Following the equal sign is the value of the likelihood for the parameter value set in the `init` statement.

I don't know how the `search(off)` or `search(norescale)` solutions affect the subsequent likelihood calculations,  so these solution might still be worthwhile.

Original "solutions":

To force a start at your initial value, add the `search(off)` option to `ml maximize`:

```
ml maximize, iterate(2) trace search(off)
```

You can also force a use of the initial value with `search(norescale)`. See Jeff Pitblado's post at http://www.stata.com/statalist/archive/2006-07/msg00499.html.